# Changing the Typeface of Text String

Tags: java, android

I created a class, which extends drawable class and has a custom text in it.

Now, I want to change the Typeface of the text, and has a *.ttf file in assests/fonts.
But I can't use `createFromAsset()` method, because of the method `getContext().getAssets()` couldn't be called.

is there any way to change the typeface of the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make Context a part of the constructor as a parameter.
And call it from an activity. 
Hope this helps.